# Reading json response from PHP and pushing into javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[
  {"type":"1","text":"success"},
  {"yid":"167","uid":"15","lat":"13.0501383","lng":"77.597593","time":"2014-10-20 20:25:27","dist":1.95},
  {"yid":"204","uid":"32","lat":"13.0412773","lng":"77.6133699","time":"2014-11-17 03:15:24","dist":0.06}
]
```

This is my json response from php script. I need to store or push this in a multidimensional array in javascript. I'm able to decode the json response successfully using the below code.

```
var myLatLng = [];
var myYid = [];

post_data = {'userLat':position.coords.latitude, 'userLng':position.coords.longitude};

$.post('leo.php', post_data, function(response){
  $.each(response, function(index, element) {
    if(element.lat!=undefined || element.lng!=undefined)
    {
      myLatLng.push(element.lat+', '+element.lng);
      myYid.push(element.yid);
    }       
  });
});
```

I also need to use this values globally across different functions.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @Andy isn't  this a multidimensional array : `myArray = [[]]` ?

Comment: That's an array of arrays. Similar but not the same.

Comment: @Andy what is a `multidimensional array` so ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll want your check for undefined to be an "AND" condition, because both will have to be defined seeing that you're accessing both of them and assigning both of them to a variable in your "then" clause.

When you say "multidimensional array", you can have a multidimensional array in javascript if it only has numerical indexes. If instead you want to have key-value pairs, it will be an object and not an array.
If that is good enough for you, just push an array each time instead of pushing single values to two separate arrays:

```
var multiDimArray = [];

post_data = {'userLat':position.coords.latitude, 'userLng':position.coords.longitude};

$.post('leo.php', post_data, function(response){
  $.each(response, function(index, element) {
    if(element.lat!==undefined && element.lng!==undefined)
    {
      multiDimArray.push(new Array(element.lat+', '+element.lng,element.yid));
    }       
  });
});
```

Comment: It is usually better to use an array literal instead of `new Array`, [`new Array` can cause problems](http://jslinterrors.com/the-array-literal-notation-is-preferrable). I would have used `multiDimArray.push([element.lat + ', ' + element.lng, element.yid]);`